# How to take time out of user input date?

Tags: java, sql, xml, spring, oracle

I have a program that allows users to add an event with a date, tournament name, and location. Whenever the date that the user inputs gets saved, there is a time portion that I don't want. How do I get rid of it? The original table is in oracle, and I am using Spring framework.

[image]

JSP Page (just the input code)

```
<td style="border:0px;">
    <select name="month" style="font-family:Arial; font-size:14px; height:28px;">
        <option selected disabled>Month</option>
        <option value="01">January</option><option value="02">February</option><option value="03">March</option>
        <option value="04">April</option><option value="05">May</option><option value="06">June</option>
        <option value="07">July</option><option value="08">August</option><option value="09">September</option>
        <option value="10">October</option><option value="11">November</option><option value="12">December</option> 
    </select>

    <select name="day" style="font-family:Arial; font-size:14px; height:28px;">
        <option selected disabled>Day</option>
        <option value="01">1</option><option value="02">2</option><option value="03">3</option><option value="04">4</option>
        <option value="05">5</option><option value="06">6</option><option value="07">7</option><option value="08">8</option>
        <option value="09">9</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="13">13</option><option value="14">14</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="16">16</option>
        <option value="17">17</option><option value="18">18</option><option value="19">19</option><option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="21">21</option><option value="22">22</option><option value="23">23</option><option value="24">24</option>
        <option value="25">25</option><option value="26">26</option><option value="27">27</option><option value="28">28</option>
        <option value="29">29</option><option value="30">30</option><option value="31">31</option>
    </select>

    <select name="year" style="font-family:Arial; font-size:14px; height:28px;">
        <option selected disabled>Year</option>
        <option value="2015">2015</option><option value="2016">2016</option><option value="2017">2017</option>
        <option value="2018">2018</option><option value="2019">2019</option><option value="2020">2020</option>
    </select>  
</td>

<td style="border:0px;">
    <input id="upcomingTournament" align="middle" name="upcomingTournament" style="padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px; width:500px; height:28px; font-family:Arial; font-size:18px;" type="text"></input>
</td>

<td style="border:0px;">
    <input id="upcomingLocation" align="middle" name="upcomingLocation" style="padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px; width:300px; height:28px; font-family:Arial; font-size:18px;" type="text"></input></th>
</td>
```

Controller Java File

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/NewMatch.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String newMatch(@ModelAttribute("matchForm") MatchesVO searchVO, ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {

    String date = request.getParameter("year")+"-"+request.getParameter("month")+"-"+request.getParameter("day");
    searchVO.setUpcomingDate(date);

        if(searchVO.getUpcomingDate()!=null&&searchVO.getUpcomingTournament()!=null&&searchVO.getUpcomingLocation()!=null) {
            sampleService.newUpcomingMatch(searchVO);
            return "forward:/Matches.do";
        }

        else {
            return "sample/NewMatch";
        }

}
```

SQL XML File

```
<insert id="leagueDAO.newUpcomingMatch">

    <![CDATA[

        INSERT INTO UPCOMINGEVENTS 
            (   UPCOMINGDATE
              , UPCOMINGTOURNAMENT
              , UPCOMINGLOCATION )
        VALUES ( #upcomingDate#
               , #upcomingTournament#
               , #upcomingLocation# )

    ]]>

</insert>
```

Comment: Why don't you want the time protion? Usually the dates are always saved with the time (even if it is 00:00:00)

Comment: [`DateUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/DateUtils.html) from common-lang provides a `truncate`. You can also create a `Calendar`, set unwanted fields (hour, minute, etc) and transform back to date

Comment: I think you should store your date with the time. And just use a SimpleDateFormat to format it when you need to display it.

Comment: @bryce if I use a SDF then the date becomes a String and I don't want that because I want to put the dates in order.

Comment: @RC. can you specify how to do that? Sorry, complete newbie to programming here.

Comment: @Christine If you want to keep an order, put the dates in a sorted list, sort them and when you need to display them, iterate over the list with the SDF

Comment: What is your problem with the time of the date precisely? A display problem are a storage problem?

Comment: @bryce can I do that if they are user-inputted dates? I am using <c:forEach> to show the list of dates, not inputting them in myself. & display problem. I only want the year/month/date showing.

Comment: @Christine Yes you can. You need keep you List<Date> to do your business logic. Then you populate in a List<String> that you format with your SDF. And this is this List<String> that you display in your <c:forEach>

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose a proper DateFormat to print out Date as String. E.g. 'yyyy-MM-dd'

Answer (score 0):

[`DateUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/DateUtils.html#truncate(java.util.Date,%20int)) from common-lang provides a `truncate` function, used like this:

```
DateUtils.truncate(yourDate, Calendar.DATE);
```

You can also create a `Calendar`, set unwanted fields (hour, minute, etc) and transform back to date:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(yourDate);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
Date truncated = cal.getTime();
```

As already stated in comments, if you don't need to store the truncated date (no unicity constraint, etc), you can also just store a date with time and format it when you need to display it (see [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)).

Answer (score 0):

You could alter the insert statement in your SQL XML File to truncate the date during the insert:

```
<insert id="leagueDAO.newUpcomingMatch">

    <![CDATA[

        INSERT INTO UPCOMINGEVENTS 
            (   UPCOMINGDATE
              , UPCOMINGTOURNAMENT
              , UPCOMINGLOCATION )
        VALUES ( TRUNC( #upcomingDate# )
               , #upcomingTournament#
               , #upcomingLocation# )

    ]]>

</insert>
```